# CSS Background not showing up

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML and this CSS markup, and I have this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLAL8.png

For some reason, the image doesn't load at all, even though if I open the url in a new tab, it loads properly. When I change the image to anything else in the same folder, it works.
I feel like I'm missing something incredibly elementary here.

```css
    div#advert_bubble{
        width: 400px;
        min-height: 300px;
        position: relative;
        float: left;
        clear: left;
    }
    
        div#advert_bubble div.advert_bubble_box{
            float: left;
            clear: left;
            width: 300px;
            height: 200px;
            border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
            -moz-border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            background-color: white;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 5;
        }
        
        div.advert_bubble_arrow{
            position: absolute;
            width: 41px;
            height: 39px;
            background: url(/images/advert_bubble_arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
            z-index: 10;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="advert_bubble">
            <div class="advert_bubble_box">
                <p> Text Here </p>
            </div>
            <div class="advert_bubble_arrow"> </div>
            
    </div>
```

Comment: put your `background:url()` inside quotes: `background: url('/images/advert_bubble_arrow.png') no-repeat 0 0;` and check that the file exists at images/advert_bubble_arrow.png

Comment: It looks good here http://jsfiddle.net/7d6qoeha/

Comment: @Martin , does not need double quotes, Works fine without it too

Comment: Quotes aren't mandatory. Check to make sure the path to your image is correct. It would be www.yourdomainname.com/images/advert_bubble_arrow.png.

Comment: You got famous 404 error in Console panel , that **`Image not found :)`** , I can say without looking at your PC.

Comment: No, I'm not getting a 404, and when I open the link in a new page from the css, the image actually loads. And no, quotes aren't required. The image is in the same folder.

Comment: Is the images folder and the CSS inside same folder ? if yes, Try `background: url(images/advert_bubble_arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;` instead of `background: url(/images/advert_bubble_arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the ID its not showing up because the id is not defined. to define it do this

```html
<html>
  <Head>
    <title></title>
    <!--This is where you declare your IDs-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
     //looks for Id's here so declare them
      function Idgoeshere()
      //looks for the id.
      {
      document.getElementById
      //after the Id you say what it does.
}
      </script>

</head>
  <body>










div id="advert_bubble">
        <div class="advert_bubble_box">
            <p> Text Here </p>
        </div>
        <div class="advert_bubble_arrow"> </div>

</div>

div#advert_bubble{
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

    div#advert_bubble div.advert_bubble_box{
        float: left;
        clear: left;
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
        -moz-border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
        border: 1px solid #000000;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
    }

    div.advert_bubble_arrow{
        position: absolute;
        width: 41px;
        height: 39px;
        background: url(/images/advert_bubble_arrow.png) no-repeat 0 0;
        z-index: 10;
    }
  </body>
</html>
```